# Test if two coefficients are statistically different in negative binomial regression in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, negative-binomial-distribution

I am currently working with negative binomial regressions and I would like to test whether two coefficients in the same model are significantly different from each other in R. I have read on some answers here but none concern negative binomial regressions.

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards.

Comment: Is your confusion about what's going on mathematically or how to code it in R?

Comment: Pretty much both, actually. But my question is primarily about how to code it in R!

Answer (score 5):

If your model is $g(Y) = a + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2$ and your hypothesis is that $\beta_2 = \beta_1 + \delta$ you can reparameterize using the sum of the variables: $g(Y) = \beta_1 (X_1 + X_2) + \delta X_2$, and test if $\delta = 0$.

Comment: +1 I've never seen this trick, and it makes perfect sense! Code-wise, this would be something like `z <- x1+x2; L <- lm(y~z+x2)` and doing inference on the parameter on `x2`.

Comment: No, then the predictors are correlated, and parameter inference goes goofy. How would you resolve that?

Comment: It's also pretty common to use the avg and difference, (x1+x2)/2 and (x1-x2)/2

Comment: Whether multicolinearity is a big problem with this approach or not will depend on your specific data set.